# PHP Array walk values

Tags: php, arrays

I am sorry but I am stuck at the moment.

How can I read the individual values of this array ? With foreach?

```
Array
(
    [30706] => Array
        (
            [name] => 30706
            [model] => al553
        )
)
```

Comment: `$arr[30706]['name']`

Comment: It's not a standard array

Comment: thanks, but i mean automatically with foreach or so

Comment: And what do you want to achieve when you access the data

Comment: I would then like to store them in a database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you connect using PDO

```
$sql = 'INSERT into table (`name`, `model`) VALUES(:name, :model)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach ($arr as $data) {
    $stmt->execute([':name' => $data['name'], ':model' => $data['model']])        
}
```